# We just reached 9000 visa questions

Tags: discussion, tagging

We just reached 9000 [visa](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/visa) questions. [visa](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/visa) is by far the most popular tag on Travel.SE, followed by [usa](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/usa) with 4618 questions at this moment.

If 39,637 is the count of questions on Travel.SE, questions tagged [visa](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/visa) account for 22.7% of all questions.

Just me or do we need to open our borders?

[image: 9000 visa questions]